# How can I join several MySQL queries while excluding some results?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

MySQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12213/16

I have three tables I am trying to work with.

Table 1: `users` table (stores data for each user in the database)
Table 2: `users_fav` table (stores data for each user who has added another user as a favorite)
Table 3: `users_rated` table (stores data for each user who has rated another user)

`users_fav` and `users_rated` store the `users.uid` who is doing the rating or faving in the `users_fav.uid` or `users_rated.uid` columns and the user they are adding to `users_fav.matchuid` or `users_rated.matchuid`.

The end result I want:
I need to pull all the users from the users table who have not been rated OR favorited by a specified user.  In the sql fiddle data the user trying to pull the results is user id 1, who has several of the other users rated and faved for testing purposes.

I have constructed the joins and tried a few things but can not get the results I want. Here is what I have tried (please reference data and comments in the fiddle posted above).  It should be assumed that user id 1 is trying to pull all the users who user 1 has not already favorited or rated:

```
#attempt one shows no results
SELECT users.uid, users.gender, users.username
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_fav
ON users.uid=users_fav.matchuid 
LEFT JOIN users_rated
ON users.uid=users_rated.matchuid
WHERE users.uid > 0
AND users.gender = 0
AND users_fav.uid <> 1
AND users_rated.uid <> 1
ORDER BY users.uid ASC;
```

This shows no results at all.  I've tried joining the `users_fav` and `users_rated` tables on `uid` as well as `matchuid`.

```
#attempt two shows all results with gender 0
SELECT users.uid, users.gender, users.username
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_fav
ON users.uid=users_fav.matchuid AND users_fav.uid <> 1
LEFT JOIN users_rated
ON users.uid=users_rated.matchuid AND users_rated.uid <> 1
WHERE users.uid > 0
AND users.gender = 0
ORDER BY users.uid ASC;
```

This second query I have tried doing the exclude with the join. It seems to ignore this and returns 6 out of the 7 total users, only excluding user 1 who has a gender of 1, which is excluded in the query.

Comment: a nonrated/nonfaved user has an entry in those table or not?

Comment: @niyou yes. if you look at the inserts on the fiddle it shows which users user 1 has fav'd and/or rated. that is also noted in the fiddle comments.

Comment: Note to other question askers - **THIS** is what we want to see - data provided (and nicely set up in a fiddle, too); attempts at a query (along with descriptions of why they aren't working); a good description of the desired results (would be better with an actual result set listed, but the good description and the query attempts make the end result obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could work...

```
SELECT users.uid, users.gender, users.username
FROM users
    LEFT JOIN users_fav ON users.uid=users_fav.matchuid AND users_fav.uid = 1
    LEFT JOIN users_rated ON users.uid=users_rated.matchuid AND users_rated.uid = 1
WHERE users_fav.uid IS NULL AND users_rated.uid IS NULL
```

this will give you all who are not rated AND not faved (eventually you want OR?)

Comment: This seems to be giving me the results I am looking for. I see where I went wrong assuming <> 1 on those joins.  I'll give this a more thorough test and then mark it as answered if all holds up.  cheers

Comment: my idea was to get first all matching records and then throw those who are rated/faved away

Comment: +1 - this is the usual way to do this type of work; actually, SQL is built on finding _matching_ results, not the opposite (although there are obviously ways to do so, as you've demonstrated).  Note that a smart optimizer may not need to actually grab all results first, and may be able to simply 'ignore' the unwanted rows from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Will give you the result of all users who have not been rated AND been fav'd by UID = 1. For some reason this fiddle thingy won't show `NULL` values is you compare it to `!= 1`. Never noticed in normal sql, so no clue if this was expected :S

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_fav f on f.matchuid = u.uid
LEFT JOIN users_rated r on r.matchuid = u.uid
WHERE
    (f.uid != 1 OR
    f.uid IS NULL) AND
    (r.uid != 1 OR
    r.uid IS NULL);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12213/65

Comment: This isn't getting correct results - namely, user 4 is being included, when that user is faved/rated by user 1.  This largely seems to be because you're tagging to the wrong id column in the cross-ref tables.

Comment: My bad, i typo'd :s. Edited.

Comment: Although, now that I think about it some more, I know what else was bugging me here - if a user has been faved/rated more than once (by somebody other than user 1, of course), they'll be included that many times in the results.  I'm assuming that the OP wants a list of unique users.